# Book a demo conversion rate

Tags: navigation, marketing, conversion-rate

My employer would like to delete navigation on book a demo and retarget landing pages. What do you think about this practice? He believes that the landing page should convert the user and he shouldn't visit any other pages...What if the user would like to read more about the product / company? What are your insights? Moreover, what's a "good" amount of CTA buttons?

Comment: Think about this: If the user isn't interested to click on CTA(s) at first sight, is it good to let them abandon the page? Isn't it better to show them other pages of your website they might be interested in, so they visit them & stay in your website?

Answer (score 0):

The approach should not be assumed but measured and tested. As for the amount of CTA buttons please go for a natural organic manner. What information would users like to see before taking a decision of making a purchase ? You could also apply the Learn - Feel - Do [https://blueprintdigital.com/learn-feel-circle/#:~:text=The%20Learn%2DFeel%2DDo%20Circle,that%20customers%20experience%20a%20product.&text=It's%20a%20simple%20model%20of,people%20who%20have%20used%20them](https://blueprintdigital.com/learn-feel-circle/#:%7E:text=The%20Learn%2DFeel%2DDo%20Circle,that%20customers%20experience%20a%20product.&text=It%27s%20a%20simple%20model%20of,people%20who%20have%20used%20them).

Comment: Would you mind including a summary of the "Learn - Feel - Do" pattern or excerpt from the link you mention? If the link breaks sometime in the future, this would help your answer still be useful on its own. Also, how would one measure and test (as you suggest) the impact of the proposed navigation changes? Not saying you're wrong, but it might be helpful if you could expand on that a bit.